# Enable curl_exec() in a sub-folder

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, curl, php.ini

Curl is enabled on the server but curl_exec function is disabled for security reasons.

```
disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,
curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

I know that I can enable this function from php.ini but it will affect the entire server.
Can you help me with suggestions on how to activate this function (curl_exec) only for a specific sub-folder? I tried using .htaccess but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `disable_functions` directive must be set in `php.ini`. You cannot set this in `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`.

See doc: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

If you need different restrictions on functions per directory you can use separate instances of **PHP-FPM**, each of which can have its own `php.ini`.

See also: http://php-fpm.org/